# regex to allow special characters but not leading/trailing white space

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to allow all special characters and white space in between words only for a password input field.

If whitespace entered at the leading, trailing of string, regex should fail

Any useful javascript regex?

I tried \S this does not accept any white space, would that be sufficient?

I tried \A\s|\s*\Z , but not able to negate this.

Comment: If the `/\s/` regex matches, the result is fail. If you need to match a string that does not allow whitespace, use `/^\S+$/`

Comment: You may benefit from reading [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48345922)

Comment: @wiktor-stribiżew he says white spaces **ARE** allowed. OP wants to reject input that has leading or trailing white spaces.

Comment: If this is not longer a duplicate then you need to explain why it is different

Comment: Just use `/^\S+(?:\s+\S+)*$/`

Answer (score 1):

Using something like `[^\s]` would suffice.

Comment: `\S` is the same as `[^\s]`.

Answer (score 1):

The `\A` (start of string) and `\Z` (end of string) anchors are not supported by JS RegExp.
If you use `/\S/` it will only match any non-whitespace char, anywhere inside a string.
If you use `/^\s|\s*$/` it will match a whitespace at the start or any 0 or more whitespaces at the end.

You need

```
/^\S+(?:\s+\S+)*$/
```

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/U28JAg/1).

It will match:

- `^` - start of string
- `\S+` - 1 or more non-whitespace chars
- `(?:\s+\S+)*` - any 0 or more occurrences of

  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace chars
- `$` - end of string.

JS demo:

```js
var strs = ['Abc 123 !@#', 'abc123@', '   abc34', ' a ', 'bvc   '];
var rx = /^\S+(?:\s+\S+)*$/;
for (var s of strs) {
  console.log("'"+s+"'", "=>", rx.test(s));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if it's totally fine but in your case, I think this could apply better

> ^((\w)*){1}$

Comment: This does not allow any special characters and contains two completely superfluous capturing groups and one redundant quantifier (`{1}` is a no-op).

Comment: You are right, I want to apologize @sri because I read something totally opposite to the question done. Next time I will read it carefully.